# How do I set a listener prop on React Native `TextInput` ref

Tags: react-native

I have a need to dynamically set the `OnPressIn` prop of a `TextInput`. I have a ref to the `TextInput`, but can't figure out how to set this method.

```js
const inputRef = useRef(null);
<TextInput
  ...
  ref={inputRef)
/>


// inputRef is passed as a prop to another component, then I try to set OnPressIn. Neither of these techniques work:
inputRef.setNativeProps({
   OnPressIn: () => console.log('ONPRESS TRIGGERED'),
});

inputRef.OnPressIn = () => console.log('ONPRESS TRIGGERED');
```

How can I set this prop on a `TextInput` ref?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing "current".

```
inputRef.current.setNativeProps({
   OnPressIn: () => console.log('ONPRESS TRIGGERED'),
});
```

Also, on what occasion does your `onPressIn` need to be changed? Isn't using a condition easier?

```
const handleOnPressIn = () => {
  if (condition) {
    console.log(`ONPRESS TRIGGERED condition: ${condition}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`ONPRESS TRIGGERED condition: ${condition}`)
  } 
}

<TextInput 
  onPressIn={() => handleOnPressIn()}
/>
```

If you're aiming for performance optimisation, I believe you should also consider wrapping the setNativeProps call in a [useCallback() hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), as from the React Native docs on [setNativeProps to edit TextInput value](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#setnativeprops-to-edit-textinput-value).

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. It's not clear in my example but I'm passing `inputRef={inputRef.current}` into the component, then calling `props.inputRef.setNativeProps()`. `setNativeProps` is being called on `current` and it doesn't work.  It is for a component that needs to know about certain events on a `TextInput`. I'm trying to not tightly couple it and just have it accept a `ref`. Then it can setup the `TextInput` as needed.